# Regex if first match, then show results of second match

Tags: regex

I am trying to construct a regex pattern that will return the results of the second pattern if the first pattern is being matched. I am trying to use the special if/then/else construct, but it appears that if the `if` statement is true, the results are every single character and not the `then` pattern. How can i rewrite this regex so that it only returns the `then` matches if the `if` pattern is true? the `else` is not needed in this case. I am referring to this [article](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html). Ultimate goal is to use this with `rg`.

**EDIT**: Updating my regex because `findme` is never next to `pattern` and i understand the mistake of my logic. I am still trying to match for `findme` if `pattern` does exist using the if/then logic

My current regex is `(?(pattern)findme)` although i really prefer not to use lookaheads in this case. Regex101 is showing matching everything:

[image]

Sample text (contains both `pattern` and `findme`). There are two `findme`s. The line breaks in the sample text are intentional:

```
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error 
sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto
beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit pattern aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos findme qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed
quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam,
quis nostrum exercitationem findme ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequ
atur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
```

Comment: `(?(?=pattern)findme)` makes no sense as `findme` does not start with `pattern` and the `if` part is always false. Hence, the else part always matches, an empty string.

Comment: You would be better off doing this with code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew right right. thats why i updated my post saying i rather not use lookaheads in this case

Comment: In all the places where it doesn't find `findme`, it looks for the `else` pattern, which is empty. So it matches the empty string between each character.

Comment: Your sample text contains `pattern` and `findme` on different lines. Can you explain what you are really trying to do, because this sounds suspiciously like an XY problem.

Comment: @Barmar yes, i understand my mistake. i rather not use a lookahead in this case, so how would i go about matching for `findme` if `pattern` does exist?

Answer (score 0):

Look at explaination:

```
(?(?=pattern)findme)

If Clause (?(?=pattern)findme)
Evaluate the condition below and proceed accordingly
Positive Lookahead (?=pattern)
Assert that the Regex below matches
pattern matches the characters pattern literally (case sensitive)
If condition is met, match the following regex findme
findme matches the characters findme literally (case sensitive)
```

Try with this:

```
(?<=pattern)findme
```

Look at [here](https://regex101.com/r/bY1yT2/141)

Comment: This only works if `pattern` is right before `findme`. In his text they're in separate places.

Comment: ah, the you have added the `patternfindme` on the sample text, so it is not the same as the original data. i have updated my post a little bit

Comment: he wanted findme if before has pattern. I got it from his question